# The process cannot access the file 'E:\NewFolder\img.jpg' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#-4.0

Somebody please help me to solve this error. The process cannot access the file `'E:\NewFolder\img.jpg'` because it is being used by another process.

```
           if (btn_Submit.Text == "Submit")
                 request.requestDetail.IMAGEPATH=Chosen_File==string.Empty ? Filepath +"NoImage.png" + ext : Filepath + txt_val.Text.ToUpper().Trim() + ext;        
            else
                 request.requestDetail.IMAGEPATH = Chosen_File == Filepath + "NoImage.png" ? (Filepath + "NoImage.png") : (Filepath + txt_val.Text.ToUpper().Trim() + ext);   

            ResponseDetail response = new ResponseDetail();
            ABC_BL bl = new ABC_BL();
            response = bl.InsertDetailBC(request); 

if (response.result)
{
    if (IsImageChanged)
    {
        if(!Directory.Exists(Filepath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Filepath);

        if(System.IO.File.Exists(Filepath+txt_val.Text.ToUpper().Trim() + ext))
            System.IO.File.Delete(Filepath + txt_val.Text.ToUpper().Trim() + ext);

    }

     pb_Image.Image.Save(Filepath + txt_val.Text.ToUpper().Trim() + ext);
}
```

While executing this am getting error in `System.IO.File.Delete();`
The process cannot access the file `'E:\NewFolder\img.jpg'` because it is being used by another process.

Comment: The code above looks fine. But this looks like a winforms application so there must be some kind of GUI involved. If you got UI that is currently showing the image you are trying to delete you must first dispose of the visuals & references to that image before deleting it

Comment: yes, i did. Still am getting the same error. :(

Comment: Can you update your question to include a snippet with the ui code that displays the image?

Answer (score 0):

The other process needs to stop using the process. Tools like `Handles.exe` and Process Explorer (both from SysInternals) can identify which processes have a file open.

If you want two processes not to block each other using a file then the processes need to work together (ie. you cannot impose sharing: unless the other process knows there is sharing it is likely you'll get data corruption and crashes).

Comment: I closed all the opened process and still am getting the error.

Comment: If you closed all processes you system would have crashed. There are far more processes than the applications tab of process explorer shows. You need to find which processes have handles to the file open.